# react redux how to delete object from state array

Tags: arrays, redux, react-redux, state

I have a state array that I want to delete an object from. For example, I have:

```
[
 {
  name:'bench',
  weight: 200
 },
{
  name:'squat',
  weight: 300
 },
]
```

I want to give the user the option to delete an exercise if they wanted to, but I can't figure out how.
Here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = [];

const movementReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_MOVEMENT: 
            return [ 
                ...state, action.payload
            ];
        case UPDATE_MOVEMENT:
            return [
                ...state.map(item => item.movementName === action.payload.movementName ? action.payload : item  )
            ];
        case DELETE_MOVEMENT:
            return [
                state.filter(item => item.movementName === action.payload.movementName ? "true" : "false"  )
            ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default movementReducer;
```

With the code I have now, I get nothing returned on the page, but I can still see my state in my redux devtools, meaning it's still there. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you're filter you're returning `"true"` or `"false"` from your comparison, but both those values are truthy: e.g. `Boolean("false") === true`.

Change your movement reducer to look like:

```js
const movementReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_MOVEMENT: 
            return [ 
                ...state, action.payload
            ];
        case UPDATE_MOVEMENT:
            return [
                ...state.map(item => item.movementName === action.payload.movementName ? action.payload : item  )
            ];
        case DELETE_MOVEMENT:
            return [
                ...state.filter(item => item.movementName === action.payload.movementName)
            ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I simplified the filter function as having a ternary was redundant.

As a note, this function is comparing the `movementName` prop as that's what the original code had, but the code example you provided for those items used `name` as the prop. I am not sure which one is correct but be sure they match